# Is it possible to use polymorphism in and ASP.NET MVC [FromBody] controller method parameter?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, polymorphism

The question title might be a bit difficult to understand, but I'll try to explain what I am asking here.

I have this sort of controller method in an ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
public IActionResult DoStuff([FromBody] RequestObject reqObj)
{
  // do stuff
  ReplyObject repObj = ProcessObject(reqObj);
  // do more stuff
  return Json(repObj);
}
```

where RequestObject looks like this:

```
public class RequestObject
{
  public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling it from an Angular service like this:

```
this.http.post("/StuffController/DoStuff", { field: "field value goes here" })
```

Now this works OK. But now I need DoStuff() to handle different subclasses of RequestObj, for example:

```
public class RequestObjectA : RequestObject
{
  public string FieldA { get; set; }
}
public class RequestObjectB : RequestObject
{
  public string FieldB { get; set; }
}
```

and have DoStuff() somehow figure out whether it was given a RequestObjectA or a RequestObjectB.

Is this kind of thing possible? I have a feeling it is not as the JSON request transmits only the contents of the object, not its class, but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it is not possible.
The long answer is: your contract for the endpoint parameter is `RequestObject` class so nor additional parameter members will be respected during deserialization as nothing is known about them.

Comment: This is what I figured. Nice to know the technical details behind the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The only option in your case would be to pass a collection of key/value pairs and query them for presence of specific keys. You are welcome to accept my answer.